# add php var within url parameter

Tags: php

Current URL is

```
<?php include ("/home/domain/public_html/create/dogs.php"); ?>
```

I want to do this:

```
<?php include ("/home/domain/public_html/create/<?php $partURL; ?>s.php"); ?>
```

$partURL is predefined. Just need to parse the php include within the above URL to parse correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this

```
 <?php include ("/home/domain/public_html/create/{$partURL}s.php"); ?>
```

You can not use php tag with in a php tag like `<?php  <?php ?>?>`

Answer (score 1):

Read up on [strings in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

```
<?php include ("/home/domain/public_html/create/".$partURL."s.php"); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the PHP Tags from the "part URL" cause you are already in PHP.

```
<?php include ("/home/domain/public_html/create/" . $partURL . "s.php"); ?>
```

Comment: remember, his version will only work till you have double quotes around the string, if you go for single quotes, you will have to use this method. So dont forget that. and, welcome. :D